# Logout issue in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS `5.1.0`.  I have configured a timeout of 13 minutes for both SP and IDP.  When the SP session timesout, it redirects back to the main homepage instead of the login page.  How can I configure WSO2 to redirect to my login page?

Here is the WSO2 log:

> TID: [10] [] [2016-05-26 17:21:13,448] @abc.com [10] [IS]DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.cache.SessionContextCache} -  Context ID : 05c6ad05-265e-4df6-9808-3e900f704684 :: idleSessionTimeOut : 780000, currentTime : 1464254473448, lastAccessedTime : 1464270505882629543
>   TID: [10] [] [2016-05-26 17:21:13,448] @abc.com [10] [IS]DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.cache.SessionContextCache} -  Found a valid session corresponding to the key : 05c6ad05-265e-4df6-9808-3e900f704684

It seems that the `lastAccessedTime` was `1464270505882629543` in nanoseconds and this issue happens intermittently.

Comment: What do you mean by the main homepage ? Is it the management console ?. There is a known issue in IS 5.1.0 with regard to the timestamp calculation logic [IDENTITY-4537](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4537) which could have caused the problem you are facing. Could you try applying the security patches for IS 5.1.0 [here](http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/). Ideally this should have been fixed with patch WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-4.4.0-0092

Comment: I mean service provider homepage. I will try to apply the security patch. Thanks

Comment: @MalithiEdirisinghe Pointed security patch released in March whereas the pointed JIRA created in April. So I don't think the patch would solve the issue. Apart from that you could have posted the comment as an answer since the given JIRA explain the exact problem Agustino is facing; it not too late even in this point.

Comment: @DarRay Thanks. Added that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in IS 5.1.0 with regard to the timestamp calculation logic [IDENTITY-4537](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4537) which could have caused the problem you are facing. Please try applying the security patches for IS 5.1.0 [here](http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/).